# Physics of Landing a Rocket on a Specific Location

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, simulations, rocket-science, software

I have been working on a rocket model for the past year, and I have a question about the landing phase of the rocket flight. How do rockets, such as those from SpaceX, land on a specific location after reaching orbit? What are the factors that determine the landing site and trajectory? What are the mathematical calculations involved in the landing process? it will be nice if you can hint at type of code and algorithms used for this purpose.

Comment: This is a very broad question. Google Orbital Mechanics. For example, this might help. https://spsweb.fltops.jpl.nasa.gov/portaldataops/mpg/MPG_Docs/MPG%20Book/Release/Chapter7-OrbitalMechanics.pdf

Comment: I suggest you take a look at https://space.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Voting to reopen. The question seems focussed enough to me.

Comment: While focused, it's about space exploration and should be asked over at [space.se], not here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> How do rockets, such as those from SpaceX, land on a specific location after reaching orbit ?

The [SpaceX Super Heavy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Super_Heavy) booster stage does not actually reach orbit. it separates from its payload about $159$ seconds after launch, at a height of approximately $64$ km (space does not start until a height of at least $80$ km, or higher by some definitions).

It then performs a powered manoeuvre to change its attitude to the horizontal, shuts off its engines, guides itself during an unpowered descent using its fins as control surfaces, ignites its engines again, reorients itself into a vertical attitude, slows itself down, lands vertically on its landing pad and is then (if all goes according to plan)
caught by two mechanical arms.

> What are the factors that determine the landing site and trajectory ?

The main requirement for the SpaceX landing site is that it is remote, as the SpaceX Super Heavy test flights seem to have a habit of ending in "rapid unscheduled disassembly" (the smaller Falcon 9 has a much better safety record).

> It will be nice if you can hint at type of code and algorithms used for this purpose.

All of this complex manoeuvring must require some very sophisticated on-board guidance software. This software is almost certainly proprietary i.e. owned by SpaceX.

I think there are videos on YouTube from model rocket builders who claim to have performed a similar style of soft landing, albeit with a model rocket and from a lower altitude. You might learn something useful from those videos.

Comment: Wikipedia has a [list of Falcon 9 first stage boosters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Falcon_9_first-stage_boosters) The last booster landing to fail was in 2021. The launch cadence is accelerating. This year, 2023, the total number of launches will end up around 100. Currently the number of safe landings in succession is somehere around 200. Landings on autonomous ships out in the ocean is done because that leaves more propellant available for payload to orbit. (Names of the landing platform ships: OCISLY = Of Course I Still Love You;  JRTI = Just Read The Instructions)

Comment: Good point. I was thinking specifically about the Super Heavy test flights.

Comment: About the SpaceX development process. Over the development cycle of the Falcon rocket technology funds were tight. I estimate that the funds available were less than 1/10th of NASA payments to their contractors. In the span of, say, 10 years SpaceX surged ahead, the Falcon rocket is, say, 20 years ahead of any other rocket technology. With starship Elon Musk is determined to achieve an even faster development than with Falcon. Elon Musk is raising billions of dollars, and spending billions. The test flights have a single priority: gather data. Only one failure criterion: to not gather data.

Comment: [continued] That is: a starship flight counts as a success if the amount of data obtained allows them to sustain the intended rate of development. The later in the flight it blows up, the more opportunity for data gathering. My understanding is: the starship development process is geared towards maximum speed of development, not geared towards using the financial resources economically.